# Contract the makes other contracts race condition issue

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I have a smart contract that is making two (a token and a crowdsale) other contracts.

```
mapping (uint => myStruct) myMapping;

function start(uint uuid) public returns (bool) {
    address tokenAddress = new Token();
    address crowdsaleAddress = new Crowdsale();
    Token(tokenAddress).addMinter(crowdsaleAddress);
    myMapping[uuid].addr_t = tokenAddress;
    myMapping[uuid].addr_c = crowdsaleAddress;
    return true;
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that this basically works some times.  When I call it a few times in a row errors start to be thrown.  It works the first time or the last time.

Are `tokenAddress`  and `crowdsaleAddress` not being set by the time that they are being passed into `Token(tokenAddress).addMinter(crowdsaleAddress)`.

I tried to debug this using truffle/remix debugger, but when contracts make other contracts, things get pretty crazy.

Is there anything wrong with this code? `tokenAddress`  and `crowdsaleAddress` are address and not txhashes?  Are `tokenAddress`  and `crowdsaleAddress` valid immediately or do they take time to mine?  I'm pretty confused about where the problem is so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need to change these two addresses from local variables to state variables.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I googled that.  That would sort of help to explain how it works at the start and end. Doesn't `Token(tokenAddress).addMinter(crowdsaleAddress);` save the address to the blockchain?  Aren't `tokenAddress` and `crowdsaleAddress` supposed to be temporary?

Comment: No, you don't need to use state variables. Local in-memory variables (as you have) are exactly what you want. Your code looks absolutely fine. If you want more help, please tell us what you mean by "errors start to be thrown."